# Antidirivatives and their domain

Tags: linear-algebra

There are two balances.
Pick numbers to fill in the boxes labeled 'x' and 'y'. 
Goal: After replacing 'x' and 'y' with your numbers, both balances should be balanced. (For each balance, both sides should add up to the same total.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the root test you should be able to see that
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{k}{k+1} \right)^{2k^2} &< \infty\\
&\iff \lim_{k \to \infty} (a_k)^\frac{1}{k} < 1\\
&\iff \lim_{k \to \infty} \left( \frac{k}{k+1} \right)^\frac{2k^2}{k} < 1\\
&\iff \lim_{k \to \infty} \left(1 - \frac{1}{k+1} \right)^{2k} < 1\\
&\iff \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{1}{e^2} < 1
\end{align}
but the last step is obviously true, so the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to solve the $$\lim_{k\to\infty} (\frac{k}{k+1})^{2k}=1^\infty$$
you have to tranform it as $$\exp\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\ln\frac{k}{k+1}}{\frac{1}{2k}}$$ then you take the $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{\ln\frac{k}{k+1}}{\frac{1}{2k}}=-2$$ using L'Hopitals' rule twice.

So the Cauchy criterion gives you $$e^{-2}<1$$ which means the series converges.